# Read & Write Permissions for SSH User and Web Server

Tags: ssh, apache2, nginx

First of all, let me clarify that I've searched through Ask Ubuntu and Stack Overflow as well as have googled a lot but didn't find any concreted solution to my problem.

So I'm setting up a web hosting environment on an Ubuntu server. The server is running Nginx as `www-data` user. The issue where I'm stuck is the isolation of SSH users.

With a jailed setup, I can restrict an SSH user to their own directory but at the same time, I need to give web server write access to the directories. Now even if a user is jailed, if he knows the absolute path to any other SSH users' home directories (where the web-server has write permissions), he will be able to modify the stuff (write, delete or whatever) without any restriction using the web server.

For example a user can execute a PHP script from `/var/userone/sites/alter.php` like:

```php
file_put_contents('Creating a file with this text', '/var/usertwo/sites/create.php');
```

to create a new file `create.php` in usertwo's home directory. Am I correct?

In this scenario, what's the best way to isolate the SSH users so they should not be able to view/read each other's directories keeping the web server working without any permission issues?

Any proper guidance will be highly appreciated.